# What would be the time complexity of following Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

The steps of algorithm are:

1. Set J = N
2. Repeat while J >1
      Module A.
      J = J/2
3. Return.

I need to find the time complexity of following in Big O notation.

Comment: What is Module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Module A is a O(k) operation you observe that J is decreasing exponentially most specifically you observe that the loop  will always reapeat log n (base 2 because it is halfed at each iteration) times thus you have a time complexity of O(k*log n)